# ES6 - how to import connect-mongo (session)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In pre-ES6, this is how I import `connect-mongo` (session):

```
var MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
```

But how can I import it in ES6?

```
import MongoStore from 'connect-mongo';
let monStore = MongoStore(session);
```

Error:

```
const Store = connect.Store || connect.session.Store;
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Store' of undefined
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

With **connect-mongodb-session** which is pretty similar, you can:

```
import { default as connectMongoDBSession} from 'connect-mongodb-session';

const MongoDBStore = connectMongoDBSession(session);

var store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/tmp',
  collection: 'sessions'
});
```

Both packages (`connect-mongodb-session` and `connect-mongo`) are exporting an anonymous function that takes the `express-session` module as an argument. This function returns a *constructor* and is exported with **modules.export**, therefore it's considered a **default export** and you can import it with `import { default as NameForAnonymousFunction } from 'connect-mongo'`.

Now, I think that a good learning practice you should follow is to try to read the actual code of packages you are installing, at least the **index.js**.

- [connect-mongodb-session/index.js](https://github.com/mongodb-js/connect-mongodb-session/blob/master/index.js)
- [**DEPRECATED**] [connect-mongo/index.js](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/master/src/index.js)

Since `connect-mongo` is using `mongodb@2.2.36` and `connect-mongodb-session` is using `mongodb@3.0.11`, i've added a deprecated tag before **connect-mongo**

Answer (score 7):

You could try importing like this:

```
import * as connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';

const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);
```

From the MDN documentation

> Import an entire module's contents. This inserts myModule into the current scope, containing all the exported bindings from "my-module.js".
>
> `import * as myModule from "my-module";`

[More information can be found here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: thanks for the answer but I have this error: `var MongoStore = connectMongo(_expressSession2.default);
                 ^

TypeError: connectMongo is not a function
`

Comment: Try importing session in the same way?

Comment: sorry what do u mean?

Comment: For example if you are importing express-session: `import * as session from 'express-session';`

Comment: i just did. but still the same error `TypeError: connectMongo is not a function`.

Comment: The docs for `connect-mongo` use `require` so no help there. https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo

Comment: You could try this, but you may have the same issue? https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongostore

Comment: I will keep an eye on this and update if I find something.

Comment: thanks. it seems ok with `import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';
const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);`

Comment: i removed `* as connectMongo` then seems ok

Comment: Great news, thanks I learned something as well. Thanks for the update.

Comment: TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 3):

Tested using session-file-store, this way:

```
import expressSession from 'express-session';
import sessionFileStore from 'session-file-store';
const FileStore = sessionFileStore(expressSession);
```

For connect-mongo, should work like this:

```
import session from 'express-session';
import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo'; 
const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);
```

Comment: TypeError: Class constructor MongoStore cannot be invoked without 'new'

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same import and initialization problem while working on NestJ/Express. This code works well with my typescript codebase.

```
import * as session from 'express-session';
import * as connectMongoDBSession from 'connect-mongodb-session';
const MongoDBStore = connectMongoDBSession(session);

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: 'YOUR MONGO URL',
    collection: 'sessions',
  });

// set express middleware
app.use(
    session({
      // Other options here
      store: store,
    }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me, I'm using es7, with babel.

```
import connectMongo from 'connect-mongo';

const MongoStore = connectMongo(session);
```

Answer (score 0):

it works on me

```
    //requires
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
    const session = require("express-session");
    const MongoSotre = require("connect-mongo")(session);
    // Session Middleware
    app.use(
        session({
           secret: "secret",
           resave: false,
           saveUninitialized: false,
           store: new MongoSotre({ uri: 'YOUR MONGO URI',collection: 'sessions'}),
           })
     );
```

Answer (score -1):

in such case Server Already know About It to create session
Try This Code:

```js
const ConnectMongo = require('connect-mongo');
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'Your Secret',
    store: new ConnectMongo({client: require('./db')}),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).